# Spring Boot 2 console color

Tags: spring-boot, colors, log4j2

spring boot exception log color comes in gray, how can I make it red?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is property where you can change the pattern.

`logging.pattern.console`

The default is something like this:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx"
```

You'll want to change that last `Ex` color like this:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m %clr(%n%wEx){red}"
```

Comment: This won't change the whole line if there is an error, but it will change the Exception to red. If you want to change the whole line to red, you might have to set up a conditional in your logback.xml file for different patterns on different log levels.